# Unable to Change Font Size of Inkscape Guideline Label

Tags: fonts, gui, inkscape, size

**Introduction**

I've successfully created labeled guidelines in Inkscape (version 1.1.1) using the **following steps**:

1. Guidelines can be created by dragging from either of the rulers.
2. Upon double-clicking on a guideline, a dialog box opens.
3. The guideline can be labeled in the "label" text field
4. After confirming with "OK," the label becomes visible next to the guideline.

---

**Problem**

I've explored the options in the dialog box and preferences window, but couldn't find a way to change the font size. Is there a solution or any workarounds available for adjusting the font size of guideline labels in Inkscape seperately from the system settings?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

Inkscape 1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20)

Comment: Hi, I have reported that on the [inkscape chat server](https://chat.inkscape.org/channel/team_testing). The devs confirm that it is not currently possible to change the font size of the guide labels. This is a good candidate for a feature request.